# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'task' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]Im building a to-do list with reactJS

and typescript. But i their this error on typescript
im begginer with typescript. Somebody can help me?

Comment: just write {...tasks,...task}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any state that use setTasks on your screenshot (please provide some code and not a picture btw), but it's probably because you want to add an object to a state that you initialize with a string. So replacing a string by an object is a non-trivial action that may crash your app elsewhere.

In order to avoid that, just declare a type for your object, and specify the type of the state with it.

```js
// type object

type Task = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string
}

// state
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<Task[]>([])
```